# How to setup internet in neighbourhood, completely disconnected from regular internet?

Tags: networking

I read in past (few years back), there is this device which can be installed, like a server and delivers access to websites in certain radius. It also uses WiFi and repeaters to provide access.

This is completely insulated from regular internet. So no paid ISP is required, and run by community or a group.

I forgot the name of device which was used to do that. Searched alot but nothing that can lead me to it.

Do anyone know about it or something similar?

Comment: are you saying that it is a local LAN that has no access to the internet?

Comment: No, not LAN. Imaging setting up network in radius of 10 kms. Connected with each other, but not to regular internet.

Comment: That's still a LAN or [WAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network), if we want to split hairs.

Comment: Ideally it would be MAN (Metropolitan Area Network). I am referring to Community network. Something that anyone can setup and not by company like CISCO etc.

Comment: So this is a networks question, I'm really struggling to see what it has to do with IoT

Comment: i still do not understand how you expect to provide access to websites when you have no internet connection .......... are you referring to websites on local web servers?

Comment: it's called a webserver and a router. i'm sure there are commercializations of such a topology, but that's the basic setup you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but too big for a comment:

You have two questions:

1. how to set up a LAN/WAN
2. which hardware to use to communicate over 10km?

You should also consider whether you want some sort of centralized network, with a server or totally distributed, where everyone’s device an talk to everyone else’s without any centralized architecture.

Also, what happens if someone wanders out of range and comes back? Do they just lose contact, or for instance, if they are gathering data, should that data be synched when they return?  If so, you need [Delay-tolerant networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay-tolerant_networking) – have a look at my answer to [this question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/would-interconnected-spaceships-be-part-of-iot/1619#1619).

To be honest, I think you need to give us a lot more detail about what this LAN will be doing, for us to be able to give you meaningful help. If you update your question, I am sure that you will get better replies.

---

[Update]

Ok, so, from your comment,  you are speaking of a [Community Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_network). That helps to know – the more detail in the question, the higher the chance of a meaningful answer.

https://www.nycmesh.net/blog/how/ looks helpful – it basically explains how to do it.  I am sure that you can find more if you DuckDuckGo, and reading the experience of someone who has already done it will be extremely helpful. In fact, if you contact them, they might turn out to be very helpful. Hmmm, there’s a good business there for someone, setting up & supporting community networks.

The networking is trivial (unless you want DTN). You can simply Google, or ask on  https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

You can ask about hardware in   BUT, you will have to give a lot of detail regarding distances, the environment (single building, city centre or countryside).

If you need software to administer your network, or for other applications, then ask on   https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

You might also want to be aware of https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

I don’t know if it will make a big difference, but telling us your location & what the network will be used for might bring out some more helpful ideas.

Good luck, and please do come back later  and tell us of your experiences.

Comment: I am referring to Community network, if that rings any bell to you. Delay Tolerant Network is interesting. Yes, data will synced like regular internet, after authentication, incase it expired. 
I more interested towards hardware to set it up.

Comment: And maybe start a business advising others how to do it :-)  If you have any more details, then we can try to give even more help. Especially if you can tell us what you will be using it for, or which country you are in.

Comment: That article makes great non-technical points, like the legality of where you place antennae on buildings, or maybe you can get a grant to set up your community.  Hmmm, maybe you can get a local university interested? It would make a good project for their students.